# Expected behavior when changing a CommCare form's name under Form Properties

Tags: commcare

I uploaded a CommCare form that was built using XLSForm. Instead of the standard /data/ syntax and form name it uses the name of the file that was used to generate the form (i.e. "Screener"). If you turn off easy references you can see that the logic refers to /Screener/some_question.

Does manually changing the form name under the Form Properties (in the Tools menu) cause any unexpected issues? Is there any reason to **not** just leave it as something other than "data"?

Answer (score 1):

To change the form name you can use the form settings page.

You are no longer able to change the form name from the "Form Properties" under the Tools menu